# Ошибка в Maven : Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar"

Tags: java, github, maven

Имеется проект :  https://github.com/LugowoyKonstantin/java-helper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данный проект имел структуру с одним файлом pom.xml, но сегодня я для каждого пакета реализующего определенный функционал, создал свой модуль и соответственно свой pom.xml. Родительским (корневым) pom.xml, является java-helper/pom.xml, а остальные от него наследуются.

До сегодняшних изменений, данный проект компилировался и деплоился на GitHub, чтобы потом его можно было использовать в зависимостях для других проектов.

**Прикладываю все pom.xml**

Корневой java-helper/pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
<artifactId>java-helper</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.3</version>

<modules>
    <module>java-helper.calculating</module>
    <module>java-helper.converting</module>
    <module>java-helper.factory</module>
    <module>java-helper.filling</module>
    <module>java-helper.io</module>
    <module>java-helper.models</module>
    <module>java-helper.other</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <java.version>10</java.version>
    <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
    <github.maven-plugin>0.12</github.maven-plugin>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>internal.repo</id>
        <name>java-helper</name>
        <url>file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <altDeploymentRepository>internal.repo::default::file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</altDeploymentRepository>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
            <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${github.maven-plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                <message>Maven artifacts for ${project.version}</message>
                <noJekyll>true</noJekyll>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</outputDirectory>
                <branch>refs/heads/mvn-repo</branch>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
                <repositoryName>java-helper</repositoryName>
                <repositoryOwner>LugowoyKonstantin</repositoryOwner>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>site</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.com.robust-it/cloning -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.com.robust-it</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloning</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

java-helper.calculating/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-helper</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>java-helper.calculating</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
```

java-helper.converting/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-helper</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>java-helper.converting</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
```

java-helper.factory/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-helper</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>java-helper.factory</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-helper.models</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

java-helper.filling/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-helper</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>java-helper.filling</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-helper.io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-helper.models</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-helper.other</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

java-helper.io/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-helper</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>java-helper.io</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
```

java-helper.models/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-helper</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>java-helper.models</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-helper.other</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

java-helper.other/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-helper</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>java-helper.other</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-helper.io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lugowoy</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-helper.models</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

После таких изменений в структуре пакета и файлах pom.xml, проект при использование команды *clean* корневого Maven, выдает следующую ошибку :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ 
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ 
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ 
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ 
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ 
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ 
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 7 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.lugowoy:java-helper.calculating:1.3 (E:\Projects\IdeaProjects\java-helper\java-helper.calculating\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.lugowoy:java-helper.converting:1.3 (E:\Projects\IdeaProjects\java-helper\java-helper.converting\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar"
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.lugowoy:java-helper.factory:1.3 (E:\Projects\IdeaProjects\java-helper\java-helper.factory\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar"
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.lugowoy:java-helper.filling:1.3 (E:\Projects\IdeaProjects\java-helper\java-helper.filling\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar"
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.lugowoy:java-helper.io:1.3 (E:\Projects\IdeaProjects\java-helper\java-helper.io\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar"
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.lugowoy:java-helper.models:1.3 (E:\Projects\IdeaProjects\java-helper\java-helper.models\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar"
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.lugowoy:java-helper.other:1.3 (E:\Projects\IdeaProjects\java-helper\java-helper.other\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM com.lugowoy:java-helper:1.3, must be "pom" but is "jar"
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Выполнение команды *deploy* Maven выдает такую же ошибку.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дочерних проектах вы ссылаетесь на родительский с версией 1.3, когда ещё не было такого разделения и родительский проект создавал jar. Измените версию родительского проекта на 1.4 (вы это уже сделали на GitHub) и ссылайтесь на неё, а не на 1.3 в дочерних проектах.

Comment: Спасибо. Когда я изменил код во всех дочерних файлах pom.xml, то подучил ошибку [ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference.  По причине, что некоторые модули используют друг друга. Подскажите как ее исправить. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Значит у вас неправильная схема зависимостей или вы неправильно разделили код на подпроекты. Например `java-helper.other` зависит от `java-helper.models`, но и `java-helper.models` зависит от `java-helper.other`.

Comment: Если такое есть, то это не правильно. Только один может зависеть от другого. Зацикливает на этапе компиляции?

Comment: Зацикливание на этапе разрешения зависимостей Maven-ом.

Comment: После применения команды deploy в github, оказался только java-helper.filling. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы все собрало в один java-helper.jar? Извините. Спасибо.

Comment: Вернитесь к одному `pom.xml` для `java-helper`. Зачем вы разделили его на несколько Maven проектов, если хотите получить один jar?

Comment: Ростислав Красный, большое спасибо за помощь и консультацию.